# Why is tne console giving me only the even numbers?

Tags: c#, loops

I have to express the first 100 members of the row 2,-3,4,-5,6,-7 etc. I am new to C# syntax, still learning it and do such exercises as this one for review. I am pretty sure i know what i want: to do a for loop and nest inside it an if statement which will simply add a minus '-' in front of the odd numbers.

```
static void Main()
    {


        for (int chislo = 2; chislo < 102; chislo++)
        {
            if (chislo % 2 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(chislo);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("-",chislo);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("-" + chislo.ToString());` See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttxecb1c(v=vs.110).aspx for what you did wrong.

Comment: `Console.Write("-",chislo);` is not the [overload you think it is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xdyw6yk(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As HimBromBeere has answered, you need to add + between the "" and chislo.  Also there's no point in having WriteLine in the IF.

Here's what your code should look like if you want the numbers to be on the same row

```
public static void Main()
{
    for (int chislo = 2; chislo < 102; chislo++)
    {
        if (chislo % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.Write(chislo);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("-" + chislo + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Also since you asked why it gives you only the even numbers, because on  `Console.Write("-", chislo)` When it comes to the number 3, it goes into the else and only takes the minus("-") since you do not have a + operator between - and chislo.

Късмет! :)

Comment: Yes, concatenation was the problem, I see. Мерси! :  )

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned you are using `Console.Write("-",chislo)` incorrectly. This particular method call is attempting to do a string format using the first string as the template and the rest of the parameters (only one in your case) as the items to insert into the string. Since you have no place holders (`{x}` where `x` is the parameter index) it will not do anything and just print out the template string unchanged. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttxecb1c(v=vs.110).aspx).

To demonstrate using your original code you could do this. (I am making the assumption here that you want this all on the same line. In your example you are using a write line in the if statement which would result in a new line being started):

```
for (int chislo = 2; chislo < 102; chislo++)
{
  if (chislo % 2 == 0)
  {
    Console.Write(chislo);
  }
  else
  {
    //Using the format method correctly
    Console.Write("-{0}", chislo);
  }
  //If you want your numbers seperated by commas
  if (chislo < 101)
  {
    Console.Write(",");
  }
}
```

However if you happen to be using at least c# 6 you can use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) which allows you to put your logic into the string generation. I am not advocating the use of this in production without some clean up but it does demonstrate the alternative.

```
for (int chislo = 2; chislo < 102; chislo++)
{
  Console.Write($"{(chislo % 2 == 0 ? "" : "-")}{chislo}{(chislo < 101 ? "," : "")}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Thanks for the other answers too! One last thing. I read about the string format method that you mentioned. Is there a difference between ("-{0}", chislo) and ("{0}", -chislo)?

Comment: @KirilMladenov The output that they produce would be the same however, the first one is appending a number to the `-` string. The other is injecting the negative of the chislo number to an empty string and is a superfluous call, it would be better to call (-chislo).ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to keep in mind that I haven't seen mentioned yet. Consider the difference between the following two lines of code:

```
Console.Write("-" + chislo);  // Line 1
Console.Write(-chislo);       // Line 2
```

Line 1 is a corrected form of your original code that I've seen in other answers. But line 2 is simpler: instead of constructing a string to represent the negative value of `chislo`, it passes the negative value itself to `Console.Write`, allowing that function to worry about how to format it. I think this is a bit cleaner and easier to understand. It's also advantageous in that `Console.Write` will render the numeric value using the applicable region settings defined on the user's machine. So if, for instance, someone uses a negative sign symbol other than `-`, they'll see the symbol they're accustomed to with this approach.

Comment: Someone already did mention the above. However because it didn't explain why the OP code didn't work it was down voted so they removed it. I also pointed out that, not in this particular case, it would not work for negative numbers without changes. I do agree though it is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Bronumski. I agree that a full answer should explain the problem with the OP's initial approach rather than merely suggesting a different way to go. My answer is more intended as an addendum to the other answers that was too long to post as a comment.